# Storyboards are never in a logical place, always moving everytime I open Xcode 6

Tags: xcode

There seems to be no rhyme or reason where Xcode places 
Storyboards. Every time I open Xcode they are in a completely different spot in the editor. Is it just me? Can they be locked to stay in one position?

[image]

[image]

Comment: what do you exactly mean by spot? show some pics please

Comment: I think he means that each time he opens his storyboard in Xcode, the canvas is scrolled to an apparently random position.

Comment: Exactly! Totally random.  (added 2 images, just opened an closed Xcode). It may be something I'm doing, but I don't see any pattern. Actually this has been happening in 3,4,5 and now 6.